# mvn track down dependency google-collections-1.0

Tags: java, maven

My pom file does not depend on google-collections-1.0 and neither dependency:resolve or dependency:tree list it but it is causing a conflict with guava and a real pain. Any suggestions on how to track it down.

Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes large assembled dependencies actually contain the classes from other libraries, so you may be depending on another library that contains the google-collections classes (rather than specifying it as a dependency which you could exclude). Some IDEs like NetBeans and Eclipse allow you to inspect your project's dependencies and look at all the packages and classes they contain - this may help you find the right JAR. Alternatively, if you know a specific class that you do not want to depend on, you could try http://www.grepcode.com/, which lists the JARs a class is in.

Comment: Can you be more specific in what sort of conflict it is causing? Is this library being packaged in your `WEB-INF/lib` even thou it is not being listed by `dependency:tree`?

Comment: The file ~/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar gets downloaded when I run maven install it is causing a problem because com/google/common/base/FinalizableReferenceQueue.class
 is getting compiled from google-collections but I want to use the version from guava.

Comment: So a class from an unwanted JAR is present on your classpath when building your artifact? You are getting `NoSuchMethodException` or how do you know this is happening? (just want to understand the problem)